# Is it possible to remove the ":-)" smiley key in Swype for stock Messaging?

Tags: keyboard, swype, motorola-defy

I love Swype but have a minor gripe with it.

Many times a word will be completely messed up so I hit the backspace key but instead accidentally hit the `:-)` key.

In almost all programs there will be a return key instead. It appears to only be in the stock messaging application (though it's where I spend most of my time!).

This is extremely annoying, as I never use the built in smileys (I prefer them without the nose, e.g. `:)`). Is it possible to remove that key and make the backspace key bigger or something similar?

My phone is a rooted Motorola Defy with a stock ROM.

Comment: I thought this was contextual. Handcent, for example, has a setting that lets you toggle between the smiley button and an enter/return button. Do you see the smiley button everywhere when you type?

Comment: @eld ah it only affects the stock messaging application. Do I really need to install a different messenger to get this to go away?

Comment: Hm, I'm certainly not seeing a way to do this in the stock messaging app. That's kind of annoying if so (I turn that button off on Handcent for the same reason).

Comment: What version of Swype?

Comment: No answers here, but just wanted to contribute my experience with this, which is that on my Droid3 (OS v2.3.4, NOT rooted; Swype v3.25.91.34494) it seems to depend on who I am texting with. In some (most) cases, the keyboard includes a return key. With certain (few) people, the return key is replaced by the "smiley" key and there is no obvious way to switch that key to the return key. I am using Google Voice (v0.4.2.66) for most of my SMS messages, and where this behavior is observed.

Answer (score 2):

That's unfortunately not possible, Swype would need to provide a setting for this, which they don't. You might have more luck with third-party-messaging apps, but I doubt it, as this is a contextual feature that pops up whenever it makes sense for smileys to be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

I have Jelly Bean 4.2.2 on a HTC One S and Swype 1.4 installed. I was ready to go on a shooting spree when I thought I couldn't hit a return button to start a new line!

I opened a SMS thread, tapped **Menu** > **Settings** and scrolled all the way down. There is an option at the bottom called **Soft keyboard type**. Open that and you get --

**<> Smiley key**

**<> Send**

**<> Enter for a new line**

Select the bottom one and you're golden!

This setting will change it for both the stock Android keyboard *and* Swype.

Cheers!